# How can I create a vertical line (with radius) on the left side of a paragraph?

Tags: css

I'm pretty new to front-end so struggling a little bit. 
I'm trying to create something like this photo:

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKfaf.png)

1. Create a vertical line that has the same height as the content on the right.
2. Add radius to that line. Don't know if this is possible?

-- Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check this pen I made for you. You just need to change the colors.

I'm using a `div` with a `heading` and a `paragraph` tag in it. I'm placing it relative.
After that I'm using a `::before` on the wrapper element that's absolute positioned to the wrapper element itself, and the position is topleft.

[Link to pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewzrwj)

Let me know if something is unclear.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.wrapper::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>This is a header</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quisquam deserunt voluptate aspernatur sequi perferendis mollitia cum maxime voluptatum vero!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @tyla would you mind setting this as the accepted answer if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

using pseudo element

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  
}
p{
font-size:30px;
  position:relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

p::after{
  content:"";
  width:5px;
  height:100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<p>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test {
  font-size: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  box-shadow: -40px 0 0 0 #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">Hej<br>med<br>Dig</div>
</body>
</html>
```